# Bluetooth Firmware Update

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, microchip, firmware

I have a BLE module that i'm trying to update the firmware in, but having a lot of problems connecting the recommended update software (ISupdater). All I get is 'connect failed' message. There seems to be no troubleshooting information available, so I hope that someone has run into the same issues and solved it.

For the hardware setup, I'm connecting to a PC via a USB-USART serial adapter board. I have the 3.3V, GND, reset switch, mode switch, USART connection from the RN4870 BLE module connected as per the microchip connection diagrams (https://microchipdeveloper.com/ble:rn4870-app-example-fw-upgrade). I have verified many many many times that my connections are correct.

[Connection Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFdC2.jpg)

To test the BLE connection and data transfer I have mobile devices (iOS and Android) with the recommended apps (SmartData, mBIoT). I can see the BLE broadcast in the bluetooth lists, and I can connect to it to use the apps.

For the RN4870 module, I'm able to connect to CoolTerm software to test that I'm getting communication between the terminal and a mobile device. I'm able to send and receive data on the CoolTerm terminal, and on the mobile device apps, so that suggests to me that the USART adaptor is working correctly, and so is the BLE module.

In CoolTerm, I'm able to enter the CMD mode for the RN4870 module to set and read settings of the module, so I can check and set the baudrate to the default 115200.
If I use a BM70 module (which is the same hardware as RN4870 but different firmware), i can't enter any CMD mode, or do any sort of reset. The data is still able to be sent and received, so that confirms the baud rate is correct.

When I attempt to connect to either BLE module using the ISUpdate software that is recommended in the update steps to use as the firmware updater, I'm not able to connect to the module to update the firmware. I've tried many times to get the software to connect, many different ways, without success, and it's frustrating to no end.

I've updated the MCP2200 drivers to the latest ones from the microchip website, as well as using the latest versions of the CoolTerm and ISupdater. I've also tried previous versions, but still they all have 'connect failed'

[ISupdater Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bl79L.jpg)

has anyone got any solutions to the issue?

PC: Windows 10, 64-bit
BLE Modules: RN4870, BM70
CoolTerm Version: v1.8.0 (build 861)
ISUpdater Version: v4.0.0.207
IS187x_102_BLEDK3v1.11_UIv1.01 for Windows 10
Mobile Apps: SmartData, LightBlue for iOS, LightBlue for Android, mBIoT

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, well it turns out that the USB-USART serial adaptor (although confirmed to be working correctly) seemed to be the problem.

At first, I only had the 1 adaptor, and I had to borrow a different adaptor. After swapping this FTDI232 USB-USART Serial adaptor, the connection was made first try, and I was able to update the firmware. I have now purchased a new adaptor.

So, if you are having the same trouble, try using a different adaptor.